# Implement interface in methods (the best practice)

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, interface, anonymous-class

I have some callback interface:

```
public interface FooCallback {
    boolean doSomething(Foo fooArg);
}
```

which is implemented as anonymous block in methods in service layer:

```
public void methodA(Bar barArg) {
    // some business logic like parsing Foo object from Bar for example

    FooCallback cb = new FooCallback() {
        @Override
        public boolean doSomething(Foo fooArg) {
            // some calculation with fooArg and barArg and return boolean value
        }
    }
    saveBar(barArg, cb);
}
```

saveBar is method which is also in that class and is using to save Bar object into database depends on result of `doSomething` method of `FooCallback`;

```
public void saveBar(barArg, cb) {
    // get Foo object from database

    if (cb.doSomething(fooFromDB)) {
        // save barArg into DB
    } else {
        // antother logic
    }
}
```

I have a lot of methods like `methodA` in my service class. Anonymous code block is also bad testable. Can you tell me what is the best practice with similar implementation? I figure out move content from `doSomething` to another method, but it means every method will be self methodCallback. What do you think? I am using java. Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the anonymous block style will complicate testing, which is why I wouldn't recommend it in this case. If you'd like to stay as close to the approach you've outlined, create a class that implements FooCallback and then supply an instance of that class as an argument to the constructor of whatever class contains methodA() and saveBar(). You don't lose anything, and you gain the option of supplying a mock instance with a different implementation of doSomething() during testing.

I say if you'd *like* to, because I'm not sure exactly what advantage the whole FooCallback approach provides in the given example. It seems as if it would all be better organized if you dropped that class and its anonymous implementation entirely, and just had methodA() return a boolean used to determine if saveBar() should be used. Why create a whole interface just to contain a method that returns a boolean, instead of just handling that directly within FooSaveHandler or whatever this is all called?

**Edit to go with comment:**

If you have A-X distinct sets of logic that you need to call on a Foo in different situations, and you have logic that's conditionally calling those individual A-X methods, why not something more simple?

```
handleFooBarLogic(Foo foo){
    boolean saveBar = false;
    //Logic that originally called methodA()
    if(something) {
        return saveBar = doSomethingOriginallyFromMethodA(foo);
    }
    //etc.
    return saveBar
}    

saveBar(Bar bar) {
       //Just saves a Bar
    }
```

If we're talking best (or at least better) practices, your saveBar() is doing a lot more than saving a Bar, and by that point it should already have been determined that a Bar needs to be saved. Working backwards from that premise eliminates the need for the callback entirely, and the interface along with it. You end up with a big honking if statement, but at least things are more testable and it's ultimately easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: Problem is that every methodA, B, C, ...X has different implementation of doSomething, but we need that interface because of polymorfism and call doSomething on passed FooCallback instance.